# Does anyone know when Swift apps can be submitted to the app store?

Tags: app-store-connect

Similarly, does anyone know when apps built using Xcode 6 can be submitted to the App store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Apple website:

> You can begin using Swift code immediately to implement new features in your app, or enhance existing ones. New Swift code co-exists along side your existing Objective-C files in the same project, making it easy to adopt. And when iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite are released this fall, you can submit your apps to the App Store and Mac App Store.

ref: https://developer.apple.com/swift/

Comment: Just as an additional indicator, this blog site suggests Xcode 6 will be released in September http://fortheloveoftech.com/2014/07/21/xcode-6-beta-4-is-released-as-swift-comes-closer-to-a-public-release/comment-page-1/